# How do I prevent a link on an overlay page from opening in another overlay page in Drupal 7?

Tags: modal-dialogs

I have created a custom module that opens up a page in the admin overlay.  Upon going to that page, a PDF is generated and the link to the file is displayed on the page.  I created the link using `l()`, and gave the link a target attribute of '_blank' to open in a new tab/window.

```
l('Click here to download your PDF file.', $f_url, array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank')))
```

The link looks like it is generated correctly.

```
<a href="http://xxxx.com/sites/default/files/custom-pdf/xxxx_4.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to download your PDF file.</a>
```

When I click on it, it opens in a new window, but somehow the overlay fragment is tacked onto the end of the URL in the new window address bar, which appears as the following:  http://xxxx.com/sites/default/files/custom-pdf/xxxx_4.pdf#overlay-context=test.html.

The browser throws up a dialog box with a title of "Adobe PDF Document" and a message alert of "This operation is not allowed".

If I click this link from a non overlay page, it does exactly what it's supposed to do: Open the PDF in a new window.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on here.

How is the overlay fragment being appended to the URL, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

There is a [patch here](http://drupal.org/node/771036#comment-5670590).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  Since the feature I was working on had to get done right away, I had to actually code to avoid this situation, which was far from ideal. I'm glad to know there is a fix for when this comes up in the future as I'm sure it will.